# Is it possible to override “hard-wired” style information with CSS?

Tags: html, css, github

I'm writing [an extension for Jupyter Notebooks](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/leftaroundabout/IHaskell-tables/blob/master/README.ipynb) that generates html tables. Jupyter notebooks can be nicely [viewed directly in Github](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/IHaskell-tables/blob/master/README.ipynb), but unfortunately all `<style>` tags are stripped from the html, and those are (AFAIK) the only way to embed CSS. As a result, the tables look rather ugly when directly viewed on Github.

One possible workaround would be to use hard-baked `style=...` attributes, but apart from being inelegant this also doesn't offer enough flexibility to properly implement features like tooltip text, which I'd like to add.

I wouldn't mind too much if those tooltips just *didn't work* on github, but if I implement them the usual CSS way then instead all tooltips will be visible *all the time*!

Is it possible to write html elements in such a way that they will be hidden if no CSS information is found, but can be made visible via CSS? Or, more generally, is it possible to hard-code a default style in html, but override it with proper CSS clauses?

Comment: Are all `style` tags stripped, or only `style` tags in the `head` section? is `javascript` stripped as well, or can you use `javascript` to add properties or load data?

Comment: All `style` tags in the `<div class="rendered-html">` are stripped; I think this happens right when the `.ipynb` files (a JSON format) are parsed by Github. I don't think there's another way to embed CSS in Jupyter notebooks, but I could be wrong. — I haven't tried Javascript yet; presumably custom JS is also removed by Github, but I would accept a Javascript answer regardless if that is the only way to achieve the goal (even if it's not applicable to Jupyter/Github).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you can simply used the `!important` tag. An example could be for background color: `background: #ccc !important;`

Comment: Yup, that works! I now [have tooltips in the Jupyter notebooks](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/leftaroundabout/IHaskell-tables/blob/master/README.ipynb), which just stay hidden [when viewing directly on Github](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/IHaskell-tables/blob/feature/CSS-tooltips/README.ipynb).